# where can I find information on .scf file

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp

It looks like there is a file type called .scf which is recognised by windows as windows explorer command
The file is a text file and looks like the code in an autorun.inf file
There doesn't seem to be any documentation about it it seems to exist since Windows 3.1 to Windows 7 (not sure about windows 8)
Only 3 commands seem to exist: view channel, show desktop and open an explorer window
Is there any way to make an scf file do anything more elaborate?
One thing that interests me about this is that scf extension does not show up in windows explorer even when displaying extensions is enabled and the scf file be made to have any desired icon
If it can be used to do more nasty stuff then it would be so easy to make it look like a text file or a jpg file
Is there any way to program scf files to do anything interesting?

Comment: A quick search only returned this [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190355) and this [interesting thread](http://www.governmentsecurity.org/forum/topic/19459-danger-of-scf-files-windows-explorer-command/) with useful info.

Comment: No-one said your question was invalid.

Comment: The icon can be used to steal Windows credentials. `*.scf` files from external sources are dangerous, even when you just use Windows Explorer to browse the folder that contains them. See [Chrome on Windows has credential theft bug @ The Register](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/05/17/chrome_on_windows_has_credential_theft_bug/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [article in German.](http://www.michael-schummel.de/2007/09/29/windows-scf-dateien/) Use a translator if you can't read it. You should not use it any more. Code PowerShell scripts instead.